# ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension , what can I do here?

Tags: python, matplotlib

am trying to create a simple graph for US yields but am stuck with this error: `ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1,) and (22,)`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


 for i in range(1,32):
  Date= ['05/'+str(i)+'/2018']
    Yield = 

 [1.68,1.69,1.68,1.67,1.69,1.69,
 1.68,1.69,1.68,1.70,1.69,1.69,1.70,
 1.68,1.71,1.73,1.76,1.74,1.70,1.77,1.77,1.76]

plt.plot(Date,Yield)
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Percentage')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Did you try print `Date` and `Yield`? You are overwriting `Date` in the loop.

Comment: Yes, it appears that there is something wrong in the logic, could you please tell me how could I rewrite it the right way ?

Comment: I do not know what dates are you planning to have under `Date`.

Comment: It is ok Visag had wrote me the solution , anyways thanks for your concern

Comment: This is a very bad way of getting dates. look into [date_range()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html?highlight=date_range).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Date = []
    for i in range(1,32):
      date = '05/'+str(i)+'/2018'
      Date.append(date)
```